# GCDAsyncSocket doesn't write once the socket is connected

Tags: ios, gcdasyncsocket

In my iOS App I use `GCDAsyncSocket` library to communicate with a local server running on another iPad. So multiple iPads communicate with each other locally, and one of them acts as a server.

When a client connects to the server iPad the following `GCDAsyncSocketDelegate` triggers:

```
func socket(_ sock: GCDAsyncSocket, didConnectToHost host: String, port: UInt16) {
    sock.readData(toLength: UInt(UInt64.byteWidth), withTimeout: -1, tag: 0)
    delay(0.1, queue: socket.delegateQueue, closure: { [weak self] in
        sock.write(dataToSend, withTimeout: -1, tag: 0)
    })

    connected = true
}
```

Once the client is connected to the server, it writes some data to that socket (server), however, this data doesn't reach the server. But, if I wrap the write call in a delay function then the data will reach its destination.

Here is my delay function:

```
func delay(_ delay: Double, queue: DispatchQueue?, closure: @escaping () -> ()) {
    let delayTime = DispatchTime.now() + Double(Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))) / Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
    let q = queue ?? DispatchQueue.global()
    q.asyncAfter(deadline: delayTime) {
        closure()
    }
}
```

What I am missing here?

Comment: does the delegate method didWriteWithTag fire after calling the write method ?

Comment: @AfnanAhmad it is

Comment: what is the timeout value you're using for read and write methods ?

Comment: 30.0s for reading timeout and -1 (never) for writing

Comment: if didWriteWithTag delegate method is firing that means the data has been written, the problem is on the reading side. As a plus, do you also check didWritePartialDataOfLength delegate method if it's firing ? You can use this to see if the whole data is being written.

Comment: or it could be that read and write can't be used at the same time and there must be a little delay between their calls.